# Access user/document folder of other account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

Perhaps I just need to change my search query because I find it strange I cannot find this on Google. Anyway, I need access to the documents and perhaps user folder of another account I do not have the password of. My last resort would be to connect the disk to another computer but it's a laptop. I have administrator privileges on this laptop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is `access user/document folder of other account` unclear? I need to access a folder that is bound to another account.

Comment: It isn't clear how you are attempting to access the user profile directory from another installation of Windows.  Since you have not physically connected the old HDD to the machine, knowing how you are attempting to access the data, is vital information.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you've done in an attempt to solve your problem and where exactly you're stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user profile data are stored here by default: c:\users\

As you are an administrator, you can just browse in this directory.

Comment: It loaded for 5 minutes then when I got back I'm still in `C:\users\`. Tried it again and it still loaded very long but when I returned I got in. Followup question, why does it load so long?

Comment: @Madmenyo it takes so long the *first* time because your account doesn't automatically have permissions at access that folder hierarchy.  When you double-click on it the first time, your account with admin privileges is added to the access control list.  When you check the properties of that folder and scrutinize  the `Security` tab after your initial effort, you will now see your admin account added to the list.  Subsequent "visits" will open it rather quickly.